# Select init value in detecting value changings query

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I've got a query where I detect a value changes

```
            With RankedDates As
            (
                Select T1.RecTime, T1.Col, T1.Message, T1.ismsg
                    , Row_Number() Over( Partition By T1.Col Order By T1.[RecTime] ) As Num
                From [ActvXDeltaOut] As T1
            )
            Select T1.[RecTime], T1.Col
                , T1.Message As InitialValue
                , T1.ismsg As Value
                , T2.[RecTime] As ChangedDate
            From RankedDates As T1
                Join RankedDates As T2
                    On T2.Col = T1.Col
                        And T2.Num = T1.Num + 1
                        And T2.ismsg <> T1.ismsg
```

But when first value is 1 i need to store this node too, so initial value must be 0, not first value from the query because if I got 1->0 I will never know there was 1, but I need to know it. And if there is 0 I don't care.

for example if I got first node alike :

> 2011-03-01 00:00:00.000   1   Message

I need to get it.

**added :**

I've got a data stack **without T2.ismsg <> T1.ismsg** alike :

2011-03-01 00:00:00.000 PBSU311PBSU311_F    Длинное сообщение                                                                                                                                                                                           1   2011-03-01 00:10:00.000
2011-03-01 00:10:00.000 PBSU311PBSU311_F    Длинное сообщение                                                                                                                                                                                           1   2011-03-01 00:20:00.000
2011-03-01 00:20:00.000 PBSU311PBSU311_F    Длинное сообщение                                                                                                                                                                                           1   2011-03-01 00:30:00.000
2011-03-01 00:30:00.000 PBSU311PBSU311_F    Длинное сообщение                                                                                                                                                                                           1   2011-03-01 00:40:00.000
2011-03-01 00:40:00.000 PBSU311PBSU311_F    Длинное сообщение                                                                                                                                                                                           1   2011-03-01 00:50:00.000
2011-03-01 00:50:00.000 PBSU311PBSU311_F    Длинное сообщение                                                                                                                                                                                           1   2011-03-01 01:00:00.000
2011-03-01 01:00:00.000 PBSU311PBSU311_F    Длинное сообщение                                                                                                                                                                                           1   2011-03-01 01:10:00.000
2011-03-01 01:10:00.000 PBSU311PBSU311_F    Длинное сообщение                                                                                                                                                                                           1   2011-03-01 01:20:00.000
2011-03-01 01:20:00.000 PBSU311PBSU311_F    Длинное сообщение                                                                                                                                                                                           1   2011-03-01 01:30:00.000
2011-03-01 01:30:00.000 PBSU311PBSU311_F    Длинное сообщение                                                                                                                                                                                           1   2011-03-01 01:40:00.000
2011-03-01 01:40:00.000 PBSU311PBSU311_F    Длинное сообщение                                                                                                                                                                                           1   2011-03-01 01:50:01.000
2011-03-01 01:50:01.000 PBSU311PBSU311_F    Длинное сообщение                                                                                                                                                                                           1   2011-03-01 02:00:01.000
2011-03-01 02:00:01.000 PBSU311PBSU311_F    Длинное сообщение                                                                                                                                                                                           1   2011-03-01 02:10:01.000
2011-03-01 02:10:01.000 PBSU311PBSU311_F    Длинное сообщение                                                                                                                                                                                           1   2011-03-01 02:20:01.000
2011-03-01 02:20:01.000 PBSU311PBSU311_F    Длинное сообщение                                                                                                                                                                                           1   2011-03-01 02:30:01.000

**with T2.ismsg <> T1.ismsg I ve got nothing**

If first ismsg = 1 , as I've got here, for each Col (T2.Col = T1.Col) I need to output this first node , alike :

2011-03-01 00:00:00.000 PBSU311PBSU311_F Длинное сообщение 1 2011-03-01 00:10:00.000

So I need somehow to init default ismsg for all Cols to 0 to get it

Comment: There are other ways of doing this "islands" problem that do not require a self join. If you supply a script to populate a table variable representing `ActvXDeltaOut` and desired results I'll supply an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put:

```
        From RankedDates As T1
            Right Join RankedDates As T2
                On T2.Col = T1.Col
                   And T2.Num = T1.Num + 1
        Where T2.ismsg <> T1.ismsg
           Or T1.Col IS NULL
```

---

Can you try:

```
        From RankedDates As T1
            Join RankedDates As T2
                On T2.Col = T1.Col
                    And T2.Num = T1.Num + 1
        Where T2.ismsg <> T1.ismsg
            Or ( T1.ismsg = 1
                And T1.Num = 1
               )
```

Comment: it's not exactly what I wanted to have ) I need it to process it (add this node) only when ismsg is 1 for each Col. I can't process NULL Column ... Even can't fully understand full logics of this.

Comment: Post some sample table data with what you want returned.

Comment: Would my answer be what you want, if NULLs were turned into 0 ?

Comment: @ypercube, I added more description with example on a question.